# Clock input validation

Tags: angular7

I'd like to validate an input that should be in this format: 00:00 (hour:minutes) so no characters can be used, just a normal clock format! Any idea?

```
<input [(ngModel)]="item.time_in" [disabled]="isLock" value="{{ item.time_in }}" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) with a regex that checks for the time:

`(\d{2}):(\d{2})`

The pattern validator allows you to check if your control's input matches a regex string.